# R: matrix whose elements are any kind of object

Tags: r

I need to create a matrix whose elements may be any kind of R object.

```
string 1         string 2  ...    string n  

object[1, 1]    object[1, 2]     object[1, n]
...              ....             ...
object[n, 1]    object[n, 2]     object[1, n]
```

(string 1, ..., string n should be the labels of the columns)

Does such a matrix exist? Thanks in advance

I tried:

```
vect1<-c(returns1, returns2, returns3, returns4)
vect2<-c(param1, param2, param3, param4)
vect3<-c(param5, param6, param7, param8)

frame<-data.frame(vect1, vect2, vect3)
```

returns1, ..., returns4 are "xts" "zoo" objects

param1, ..., param4 are portfolio objects from the fPortfolio package:

```
class(param1)
[1] "fPFOLIOSPEC"
attr(,"package")
[1] "fPortfolio"
```

param5, ..., param8's class is : "character"

Nevertheless:

```
frame<-data.frame(vect1, vect2, vect3)
```

Gives me an error: R is unable to convert the "fPFOLIOSPEC", package = "fPortfolio" class into a data.frame...

So data.frame is not able to include fPFOLIOSPEC, fPortfolio elements...

Would you now how to include that kind of object in a matrix-like structure?

Answer (score 0):

In a matrix ALL columns must have the same type (numeric, character, factor, etc.).

You can build a data frame if every column have a different type (numeric, character, factor, etc.), but for each column you can only hold data of the same type (otherwise, they elements will be converted to the same type; the general rule of thumb for R is “the bigger type wins”).